# Can I Backup outlook emails from a HTC one M7 to my pc

Tags: email

Hi I have a HTC one M7 with a outlook server mail setup on it. The server IP addresses have changed but I would like to be able to retrieve the emails from the device to keep on file for my pc. I have spent a long time searching and am unable to find anything I also looked in the default HTC mail client but nothing helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope HTC Sync Manager can help you for taking backup of your outlook mail as well.

Refer this link for more details:

http://htc-one.wonderhowto.com/how-to/easiest-way-back-up-restore-sync-files-between-your-computer-htc-one-0154463/

Step 1 - Install HTC Sync Manager

Step 2 - Run HTC Sync Manager

Step 3 - Sync Files

Comment: Thankyou will try htc sync but I believe it only backups media and photos by any chance do you know a different program that may be of interest?

Comment: I just made a ADB backup would that work I really need to back them up as I plan to install custom roms on this device